# how to enable pci hotplug support in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: linux, operating-systems, linux-kernel, ubuntu-13.04, hotplug

Kindly help. I have a pci-based wifi adapter which is not getting detected when i plugged it into the laptop.

OS: Ubuntu 13.04

Kernel version: 3.8.0-19-generic

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I got the answer. Hotplug Flag is enabled by default in linux. Follow the below steps to get pcie card detected

1. modprobe pciehp pciehp_force=1 (optional)
2. modprobe acpiphp

also you can add acpiphp in /etc/modules file. This will make sure acpiphp will be loaded by default during every reboot.